# Angular CLI looking for router module in wrong place? "router_module not found"

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have an issue:

Based on the trace, my code is looking for the router module in the wrong place, it should be looking in my `node modules\@angular` folder but its looking in my `src\app\` folder, how can i fix this?

**How I got here**

I've installed angular 2 using angular cli, when I go to use the router module to create my routes, I import it like so:

```
import { RouterModule } '@angular/router/src/router_module';
```

and then use it passing in my routes like so:

```
export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES, {enableTracing: true});
```

now when it goes to compile i get the following error:

> Failed to compile.
>
> ./src/app/app.routing.ts Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
>
> '@angular/router/src/router_module' in 'C:\path\to\src\app' **<== important part ?**
>
> @ ./src/app/app.routing.ts 3:0-84
>
> @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
>
> @ ./src/main.ts
>
> @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200 ./src/main.ts

I've checked that  `node module/@angular/router/src/router_module` exists, and it does... I'm really stumped

angluar cli v1.0.1

angular v 4.4.6

Comment: Try using this as your import: `import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';`, Get rid of the `/src/router_module` on the end of the path, and don't forgot the `from`.

Comment: That did it for me, thanks alot, put it as an answer and i'll select it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this as your import:

```
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
```

Get rid of the `/src/router_module` on the end of the path, and don't forgot the `from`.

I don't know what IDE you are using, but I use VS Code. Sometimes, when I use the Ctrl+. (control period) to get the IDE to add a reference for me, I get some extra stuff in the path like what you had.

Something to watch out for!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to check the `import {RouterModule}` statement , VScode adds up unnecesary path.
Recompile it with just below statement

```
import{RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option that can be implemented is installing the required dependancy.Use this for future reference.

```
npm install @angular/router
```